# HTML5 meter doesn't display value in Firefox (ok in Chrome and Edge)

Tags: html, css, browser, meter

HTML5 meter doesn't display value in Firefox, but works fine with Chrome and Edge.

Here is how it looks in Chrome/Edge: At the right of the label, we can see '48V' and '5A' below

[image: Meter in Chrome or Edge]

Here is how it looks in Firefox: we don't see '48V' and '5A'

[image: Meter in Firefox]

```css
meter {
  justify-content: right;
  width: 135px;
  height: 22px;
}

meter::after {
  content: attr(value) " " attr(title);
  top: -22px;
  left: -50px;
  position: relative;
}

.c_meter {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 22px;
}

.c_meter meter {
  position: absolute;
  left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<status class="lbl-group">
  <div id="status">
    <div class="output-group" id="batt-group">
      <div class="c_meter">
        <label for="batt_volt">Battery Voltage</label>
        <meter id="batt_volt" min="0" low="0" high="50" max="53" optimum="48" value="0" title="V"></meter>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="output-group" id="batt-group">
      <div class="c_meter">
        <label for="batt_curr">Battery Current</label>
        <meter id="batt_curr" min="0" low="0" high="10" max="13" optimum="5" value="0" title="A">45</meter>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</status>
```

Does anyone know how to make this work in Firefox?

I expected that it would work in Firefox. I don't know what to try. Results are shown above.

Comment: Firefox [does not support](https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/) `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements on the `<meter>` element, nor indeed on the `<input>` element. Refer also to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/css-gencontent), see the Known Issues tab. You’ll have to choose between having clean ideal code with your app being broken in Firefox, and implementing it a different way.

Comment: You should never add a size unit such as Amphere or Volt in a pseudo-element for accessibility reasons. use the `abbr`  tag for units and an `output` element for the value instead!